# Default hour of day when setting Deadline or Scheduled in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Hello everybody it is quite easy question.

I'm using org-mobile so it synchronize my android agenda with org mode.

When I use `org-deadline` (`C-c C-d`) and I choose today,
the format will look like this: `DEADLINE: <2015-08-03 Pzt>`,

I just want it to make all deadlines always be at 10 am instead, like this: `DEADLINE: <2015-08-03 Pzt 10:00>`.
I would also like the same behaviour with `org-schedule` (`C-c C-s`).

How can achieve this?

Comment: You can type in a date with time at the prompt like this:  **January 5, 2015 10:00**.  You can also insert the current date programmatically with a specified time like this:  `(org-deadline nil "10:00")` or `(org-scheduled nil "10:00")`.  Look at the doc-string for `org-read-date` to familiarize yourself with the acceptable formats -- `M-x describe-function RET org-read-date RET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-deadline` works by calling `org-add-planning-info`, with `org-deadline`'s input (`nil` if you call it with `C-c C-d`) and gets a default time from `org-parse-time-string`, which is hard-coded to today at 00:00.  So there is no variable we can easily change to set the default time.

This default time is then passed to `org-read-date` which gets the user input and *does* take an argument letting us set our own default time.  Thus, we can advise `org-deadline` to call a different version of `org-read-date` whose default time is some value we set:

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defvar org-deadline-default-time "10:00"
  "The default time for deadlines.")


(defun advise-deadline-default-time (deadline-func arg &optional time)
  (let ((old-time (symbol-function #'org-read-date)))
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function #'org-read-date)
               #'(lambda (&optional a b c d default-time f g)
                   (let ((default-time (or default-time
                                           org-deadline-default-time)))
                     (apply old-time a b c d f default-time g)
                     ))))
      (apply deadline-func arg time)
    )))

(advice-add #'org-deadline :around #'advise-deadline-default-time)
```

Comment: I don't know. It does not work directly when I copied it. Nothing changed When I used C-c C-d

Comment: I've edited in some bug fixes.  It's working for me except with when there is already a deadline on the entry.

Comment: Thanks for help as you say its work like you say, now I am reading Lisp book, When I finish my first code fixing will be for this thanks for help
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have just find  [orgbox](https://github.com/yasuhito/orgbox) mode which works like how described in question.

Here's a picture which describe how it is work

[image: orgbox-pic]